# Unable to open a GIF in Xamarin Forms via Webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/GifProject

This is the project that I am following.
When I run the code I get no crash but the image does not show either. On iOS I get a "?" symbol and on Android I get the classic imagesymbol when you can't find the file.

Interface:

```
namespace GifProject.Interface
{
public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
}
```

Rendererers:
iOS:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_iOS))]
namespace GifProject.iOS.DependencyService
{
public class BaseUrl_iOS : IBaseUrl
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
    }
}
}
```

Droid:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace GifProject.Droid.DependencyService
{
public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "file:///android_asset/";
    }
}
}
```

Been doing a lot of googling  about GIFs in Xamarin forms but i have not been able to make it work ye so any tips, advice, optional solution is very appreciated!

Comment: Hey ! I just saw your question randomly.. Sorry but I don't work on this since a moment, I hope you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is your html source string. The "width" and "height" works differently on different browsers. For example my testing showed that Android cannot render an image if you specify width in percentage, it can only in pixels.
So, what works for sure is removing width and height in percentage (in pixels works)

```
string imgSource = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get() + value; //Android and iOS don't seem to need Dependency just "value", so you might use Device.OnPlatform if you wish

html.Html = String.Format(@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>", imgSource);
```

Couple questions/suggestions to think about

1. If you use the same image you might want to put in PCL
2. In Android you used Assets. Why not Resources?

Good luck

Comment: Does not seem to work (when I try it on iOS atleast) I get like a white small square in the top left

Comment: And the background gets black

Comment: If i run it on a iOS simulator i get a "?" image in the top left corner

Comment: try on iOS string imgSource = value;

Comment: Hell yes! Works good :) It does not layout correctly though according to the AbsoluteLayout but that is another question! Thanks a lot

Comment: Great. See my comment about Dependency  inside the answer